# Django blog posts not being returned

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django and have been following through the blog tutorial from the book: "Django by Example."

The code below should return all blog posts with a status of "published" but it refuses to work. What appears to be the correct page loads up using the list.html code but there are no posts showing. I have double checked and I am creating posts with the admin site with the status set to "published." I am not sure if the problem is with the template, model, views or URLs so I am including it all here:

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

#Data model class for creating posts table enrties in database

#Custom manager. Limits returned querysets to ones with published status
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset()\
    .filter(status='published') #super used to call get_queryset method from parent class as it is currently being
                                #overridden here.

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft', 'Draft'), ('published', 'Published'),)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')    #A field for use in building urls
    #slug = models.SlugField(slugify(title))
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts') #Each post written by a user and a user can write many posts
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    objects = models.Manager() #The default manager
    published = PublishedManager() #Custom manager

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.strftime('%m'),self.publish.strftime('%d'), self.slug])
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'Posts': 'posts'})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, status='published', publish__year=year, publish__month=month, publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post':post})
```

URLs.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
        r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

Templates base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h2>My Site site</h2>
            <p>This site is all about me</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

detail.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
        <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
            {{ post.title }}
        </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="date">Published{{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}</p>
    {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you please separate your URLS.py, the template, the model, and the views.py into separate box's? It is hard to tell which file it which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Post.published.all()` to use your custom manager then in your dict you are doing 'Posts' with a capital P you might want to try lowercase as your view is using `posts`. Then also the value for it was a string instead of the variable posts. So something like this should work

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: Wow. That was fast. It was the upper case p that was doing it. Thank you so much. The other things were me being daft. They were right before I changed them in ignorant confusion LOL.

Comment: Great, no problem glad it helped! Yea I tend to move things around a lot when I'm trying to figure out something too and then forget about them haha

Comment: The answer was so quick it wouldn't let me accept straight away 

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a string as your context object data:

```
return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'Posts': 'posts'})
```

Needs to be

```
return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'Posts': posts})
```

It also still isn't going to work since you have in your view and aren't calling the manager method. You have:

```
posts = Post.objects.all()
```

You need to use your customer manager.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - all posts in the database are in the "draft" status, and status='published' is registered in the PublishedManager. Change status=''draft" and everything will be OK!